# Howto use the has_filter wordpress function with an object based callback

Tags: wordpress

I have several plugins, all of which are based on using objects to hold the plugin.

In one plugin class named "test_plugin" I have:

```
apply_filter('wp_list_pages', array(&$this, 'wp_list_pages'));
```

I would like to use the `has_filter` function in one plugin to try to detect the presence of the other plugin.

I cant find any examples of the `has_filter` function being used with an object based callback.

I have tried:

```
has_filter('wp_list_pages', array('test_plugin', 'wp_list_pages'));
```

But this only returns false. I have written some debugging output to display the contents of the `$wp_filters` global variable and the callback is definitely registered in the `$wp_filters` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `_wp_filter_build_unique_id` function defined at the bottom of `wp-includes/plugin.php`.  That's where the array key for `$wp_filters` is generated.  It looks like it does something like this for your case:

```
$obj_idx = get_class($this).'wp_list_pages';
```

and then appends an integer to the end of that to make sure it's unique.  That integer is also added to a field called `wp_filter_id` on your object.

Comment: I did trace my way through this but for some reason the wp_filter_id gets left off the end and therefore the has_filter returns false.

Comment: What are the contents of the $wp_filters array?

Comment: That array holds the master list of filters and actions. Including references to the objects and functions to perform those filters.

So under $wp_filters[$tag][$priority][test_pluginwp_list_pages4]

It is the test_pluginwp_list_pages4 that _wp_filter_build_unique_id is supposed to return but for some reason it only returns test_pluginwp_list_pages without the number on the end. Which in turn causes has_filter to not be able to find the item in the $wp_filter list.

I have found a way around my current problem but it is certainly not an elegant solution and is waiting to be broken :-)